# ssh asks for passphrase not keychain password after locking keychain

Tags: terminal, macos, ssh, keychain

I'm using Yosemite and store the ssh passphrase in a separate keychain (not the login keychain). This all works fine as long as the keychain is unlocked. When I lock the keychain, I expected ssh to ask me for the keychain password, instead it asks me for the passphrase of the key. If I unlock the keychain manually before trying to use ssh, it works fine. Is this a bug, or can this be fixed by some setting?

Comment: When you say "instead it asks me for the passphrase of the key" do you mean the password to unlock the keychain and not your ssh passphrase?

Comment: It asks me for the ssh key passphrase, which is stored in the locked keychain. I would expect it to ask me for the password of the locked keychain and then use the stored passphrase of the ssh key, but that isn't happening.

Comment: I've tested a bit and see the same but I think its by default that _ssh group is allowed to use "root" access and bypass the keychain password.